# How to declare array size based on another value (C)

Tags: c

Here is my (working) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int fb=10;/*fold before 10th, starts from 0*/
    int ln[9];
    int at=fb-1; /*fold at this index, starts from nought*/
    int sl=1;/*should loop, 1=yes, 0=no*/
    while (sl==1){
        for (int i=fb-2; i>=at;--i){
            ln[i-at]=ln[i];
        }
        for (int i=fb-1-at;i<fb-1;i++){
            ln[i]=getchar();
            if (ln[i]=='E'){
                sl=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (sl==0)
            break;
        at=fb-1;
        for (int i=fb-2;i>=0;--i){
            if (ln[i]!=' ' && ln[i]!='  '){
                at=i+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (at==0)
            at= fb-1;
        for (int i=0;i<at;i++){
            putchar(ln[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At the start of main 'int ln[9]' works but 'int ln[fb-1]' doesn't work:[I get this compiler error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2057?view=msvc-170) Note: this is C, not C++.

using
#define fb 10
also doesn't work and I get errors based off not defaulting to int.

How can I get the array size to be based off of fb?

Comment: 1. You cant define array with size that isnt known to compiler in compile time                                            
                                                                            2. The macro definition fb 10 should work.         
 macros are handled by the preprocessor before the compilation therfore it should work.                                                                         
Did you remove the variable definition, before you used thw macro?

Comment: `int ln[fb-1]` is trying to declare a variable length array (VLA). This is a C99 feature but is not supported by Microsoft compilers. See the duplicate post for more details and alternate ways to achieve similar results.

Comment: @kobi Variable length arrays are an optional feature of C, one which the implementation must declare as unsupported via `__STDC_NO_VLA__ `. Most implementations *do* support it. The most notorious implementations that do *not* are microsoft implementations. Use dynamic heap allocation management if you want your code to work everywhere.

Comment: @WhozCraig, as said its a feature (starting C99). Meaning you need 'special flag'(std=c99)C89 doesn't supports.

Comment: msvc does provide [`_alloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-170) / [`_malloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloca?view=msvc-170) though - those allow you to allocate stuff of dynamic size on the stack, e.g. `int* ln = (int*)_malloca(sizeof(int) * (fb - 1))` - the syntax is not as nice as VLAs but it'll basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is a **variable length array**, and such arrays are not supported in MSVC, although they are supported in gcc.

If you're stuck with MSVC, your only option is to dynamically allocate the memory.

```
int *ln = malloc((fb-1) * sizeof *ln);
```

Be sure to call `free` on this memory after you're done using it.